# How to pass 2nd argument of useState in a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to store the input state to a array state. but when i'm passing the useState function argument to a child component it says

```
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'
```

Parent:

```
const App:React.FC = () => {
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState([])
  return (
  <div>
   <Input setcollection={setCollection} />
  </div>
 )
}
```

Input Component(Child Component)

```
interface InputProps {
  setcollection?: any[]
}
const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({setcollection}) => {
  const [input,setInput] = useState('')
  const handleChange = (e:any) => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    setInput(value)
  }
return (
   <div className="container">
     <form>
        <input onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Input Data"/>
        <button onClick={() => setcollection(input)}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Your setcollection state is accepting array you can't update like this with string value.

Comment: `setCollection` is not an array, that's the state itself. `setCollection` is a **function** which sets the state. So your type of `setcollection?: any[]` isn't quite right. Also, even after you update your input props interface so that it's a state setting function type, since you've made the prop optional you have to check for its existence before calling it, because as the error says, if its optional and in the case of it **not** being passed, trying to call `undefined` as a function would throw an error.

Comment: May i know what's the best approach on this one? i thought you can declare the state function in the props part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the TypeScript error you're getting is the fact, that you've made `setcollection` prop optional in `InputProps`. If `setcollection` can be undefined, TypeScript will treat any attempt to invoke it an error.

A button without an `onClick` event makes no sense, so it would make sense to make `setcollection` a required prop:

```
interface InputProps {
  setcollection: (input: string) => void
}
```

Note that I updated the type of `setcollection` to allow passing functions.

I'm just not sure what you're trying to achieve with it - the default value for `collection` is an array, but in the input component you're passing `string` into `setcollection`.

**UPDATE**
If you want to add input value to the collection, I'd do the following changes:

```
// App
const addToCollection = (value:string) => setCollection([...collection, value]);

return (
  <div>
   <Input addToCollection={addToCollection} />
  </div>
)

// Input
interface InputProps {
  addToCollection: (input: string) => void
}
...
<button onClick={() => addToCollection(input)}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: So what's  the best approach should i consider in this one?

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve is that every data that i get from the input state will be stored to a new usestate that's inside the array(collection) so that i can map it later on

Comment: So you want to add input value to the collection, right?

Comment: Yes. That's correct

Comment: See update to the answer

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm getting 'Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never' in the part of const addToCollection. But  i play along with these. thank you!!!

Comment: try `useState<string[]>([])`

Answer (score -2):

```
const App:React.FC = () => {
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState([])

 const updateCollection = collection=> setCollection(collection)

  return (
  <div>
   <Input setcollection={updateCollection} />
  </div>
 )
}

   

interface InputProps {
  setcollection?: (data:any)=>void
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({setcollection}) => {
  const [input,setInput] = useState('')
  const handleChange = (e:any) => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    setInput(value)
  }

return (
   <div className="container">
     <form>
        <input onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Input Data"/>
        <button onClick={() => setcollection(input)}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
)
}
```